# Use pipenv in airflow docker dag folder

Tags: python, docker, airflow, pipenv

I have created an airflow docker container. I'm using a dag folder inside my local system to create DAGs which call python scripts and use PythonOperator. I would like to use some Python packages in the DAGs and work with pipenv, but if I create a pipenv environment inside the folder, packages are not recognized by the DAG script.

Is there some way to work like this? Or is there a more proper way to do it? The work directory would look like this:

```
 - Airflow docker
   - dags
       - dag1.py
       - dag2.py
       - Pipfile
       - Pipfile.lock
   - logs
   - plugins
```

Also note that I want to use packages from github.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install additional packages in your container and work with them, option suggested in airflow documentation is building the image by yourself.

> If you need to install a new Python library or system library, you can build your image.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/index.html

Basically airflow publishes "reference" images to [their DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/airflow), `apache/airflow:latest` for the regular image, and `apache/airflow:slim-latest` for the slim version.